# trouble with WebAssembly from swc and vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, swc-compiler

My application tries to load swc with a dynamic import:

```
const swcWasmWeb = await import("@swc/wasm-web");

await swcWasmWeb.default();
```

this works fine, if the WASM-file is copied manually to

```
..\node_modules\.vite\deps
```

How can i configure vite to copy the file automatically and treat it as a dependency?

I have tried to add an import like that (see https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html):

```
import _ from "@swc/wasm-web/wasm-web_bg.wasm?url";
```

also tried to add it to the vite.config.ts like:

```
assetsInclude: ["@swc/wasm-web/wasm-web_bg.wasm"],
```

So what is the right notation?

I'm using Vite 4.0.3 with React 18.2 and Typescript.